# Do specific workers speacialize in particular duties in the game "Rule The Kingdom"?

Tags: rule-the-kingdom

I recently downloaded a game on the windows 8 app store called "Rule The Kingdom".
[image: A picture screenshot of the game]
As you can see in this particular picture, I have a worker named Gregory Oakheart. Every time someone else chops 4 pieces of wood, he only gives me 2 stone. Is this because he specialises in gathering wood from the Mighty Oaks? Thus, his surname, Oakheart, or is it because it is normal for wood to be gathered faster than stone.